# Confused about simplecov and rspec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rcov

This is code in a model:

```
  def find_tech
   Category.find_by_name("tech")
  end
```

and this is the rspec test:

```
  x = Category.find_tech
  x.name.should == "tech"
```

and the test passes. But rcov doesn't think so.

First of all why not ?

Second, if I do have to change something then what good is simplecov ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add SimpleCov's setup to the very top (line 1) of your spec_helper as stated in the Readme?

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails
```

Comment: Yup, I had spork in there too so I put it at the top of the Spork.prefork block. Neither worked.

Comment: Unfortunately Simplecov, or more precisely the underlying Coverage STDLIB has trouble with the way Spork works, which has not been resolved as of now. Please have a look at the SimpleCov github issues for more info.

Comment: By the way, the Spork setup issue has been resolved: https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/42